# .Net OracleClient Replaces Characters in Query

Tags: .net, oracle, unicode

I have a French Oracle database restored to a US server.  The NLS_CHARACTERSET for that database is AL32UTF8.  There is a VARCHAR2 field in a table in that database that can contain unicode text.  One record has a value of 'é' for that field.  I can run the following query in SQL*Plus and TOAD and everything works.

```
select * from foo where bar = 'é';
```

When I use System.Data.OracleClient to write an nUnit Unit Test and run it through TestDriven.net, it runs perfectly.  When I run the exact same code from a WinForms application, the query gets converted to the following:

```
select * from foo where bar = 'e';
```

This results in the query returning no rows from the .Net application even though it returns rows from SQL*Plus, TOAD, and a .Net Unit Test.

I know that System.Data.OracleClient has been depricated, but it still works.  This code is in a system where Oracle is being phased out, so converting or upgrading makes little sense.

The fact that the query works from TestDriven.Net (ProcessInvocation86.exe) tells me that the OCI client and OracleClient are able to accept unicode characters in queries.  That the WinForms application converts 'é' to 'e' tells me that something, somewhere in .Net WinForms is translating that.  How do I turn it off?  If I can avoid it, I don't want to have to make any Registry changes, and the application needs to work in France and the US with as few configuration differences as possible.  The goal here is to tell .Net "Don't ever convert query characters.  Always pass them all in as CLOBs which are in Unicode."  How can I do that?

Comment: The db is utf8, but what is the .net client charset?  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx) for .NET encoding/decoding

Comment: Strings are always stored as unicode internally in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (or part of it).  Adding "unicode=true" to the connection string tells the client to not translate Unicode characters.  Why this is only required for the WinForms application and not the ProcessInvocation86 Unit Test is still a mystery.